# Roulette.js: How to randomize the image spin to display all the images at least once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I like the JQuery plugin called Roulette.js:
https://github.com/akira-kuriyama/roulette.js

Ideally, I would love for the plugin to randomize the spin to see all the image at least once.

I am no great with jQuery by the way...

Thank you very much.

Eliott

Comment: If you set the : `stopImageNumber : -1,` you can have random results....is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. but I can't work out a way to show all the items at least one time before  seeing an item twice...